MapStruct's generated mapper doesn't map any properties
My MapStruct mapper doesn't work. For some reason, getters/setters are not included in the mapper method bodies (the mapper implementation is generated). It simply calls the no-args and returns the result.
May have to do with Mapstruct for some reason not seeing the generated getters/setters – even though the binding dependency is in place.
I need my mappers to be @Components in production, so I set componentModel to spring.
Here's an MRE (and a failing test)
package com.example.demo.data;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Cat {
    private String name;
}

package com.example.demo.data;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class CatDto {
    private String name;
}

package com.example.demo.mapper;

import com.example.demo.data.Cat;
import com.example.demo.data.CatDto;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CatMapper {
    Cat toCat(CatDto cat);
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for MapStruct</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.6.3</mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.data.Cat;
import com.example.demo.data.CatDto;
import com.example.demo.mapper.CatMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private CatMapper catMapper;
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        CatDto catDto = new CatDto();
        catDto.setName("Kitty");
        Cat cat = catMapper.toCat(catDto);
        assertEquals(catDto.getName(), cat.getName()); // fails: expected "Kitty", actual null
    }
}

MapStruct's implementation in full:
package com.example.demo.mapper;

import com.example.demo.data.Cat;
import com.example.demo.data.CatDto;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2024-11-14T19:21:15+0300",
    comments = "version: 1.6.3, compiler: javac, environment: Java 17.0.13 (Amazon.com Inc.)"
)
@Component
public class CatMapperImpl implements CatMapper {

    @Override
    public Cat toCat(CatDto cat) {
        if ( cat == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Cat cat1 = new Cat();

        return cat1;
    }

    @Override
    public CatDto toDto(Cat cat) {
        if ( cat == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CatDto catDto = new CatDto();

        return catDto;
    }
}

IntelliJ IDEA Community 2024.2.4. Here are my annotation processor settings (I didn't manually configure them):

It is very likely to be an IntelliJ issue. I compiled it with Maven (first following talex's advice in the comments, it's indeed important), and the generated implementation was generated alright.
It would be hillarious if it turned out to have to do with "p" ("projectlombok") coming after "m" ("mapstruct") in the English alphabet. I guess the annotation processors are applied in the classpath encounter order by default which is, in turn, natural.
This question is different: I have no compilation error. The generated code is wrong.

Try put lombok first in annotationProcessorPaths.

@talexmovedtoCodidact I copied and pasted that part from Baeldung. I tried your suggestion, it didn't work, unfortunately

@talexmovedtoCodidact you may see the edit. You were right, but that's only part of the explanation

This question is similar to: MapStruct + Lombok together not compiling: unknown property in result type. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
